# Why google chrome fails to properly display text in jQuery sortable widget?

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, jquery-ui, firefox

I am new to front-end technologies such as jQuery and css, and cannot understand why the same code renders differently.
Following code snippet is the [jQuery example for sortable widget](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#default).
 The text renders perfectly on Firefox but in chrome the text `Item 1`, `Item 2`, ... etc falls out as can be seen in the screenshot below.
**Firefox version:** 50.1.0, **Google Chrome version:**  55.0.2883.87
[image: Chrome rendering sortable widget]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
    #sortable {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 60%;
    }
    #sortable li {
      margin: 0 3px 3px 3px;
      padding: 0.4em;
      padding-left: 1.5em;
      font-size: 1.4em;
      height: 18px;
    }
    #sortable li span {
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: -1.3em;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#sortable").sortable();
      $("#sortable").disableSelection();
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
  </ul>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce using exact same code you posted and exact same chrome version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out. I had customized font in google chrome and set it to one of the [Google Noto Fonts](https://www.google.com/get/noto/). Setting the font back to default fixes this problem.